# How to request JQuery array in Liferay velocity template variable

Tags: liferay, liferay-velocity

I have this code in .vm file

```
<script...>
.....
var attr = attr0[i].id;
</script....>

#set($attr1 = $request.getParameter("attr"))
$attr1
```

How to get the jquery attribute (which is clientside) to velocity template variable which is serverside?

Comment: You can't. As you say jquery is clientside and velocity is serverside. If you want to pass something from the dom to your template you have to do a new request, passing what you need as parameter.

Comment: Thanks Marco. How to make new request, can you please point me to some documentation?

Comment: Is this velocity template part of web content,theme or layout,for better clarity on what are the available variables for the same?

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in my comment you can use a parameter, *something* like this:

1. In your template get the entire current URL (URL + parameter)
2. Check for your parameter (es. attr)

   1. If ther is the `attr` parameter and it has a value do something in your template
3. In your script create a variable with your current URL and append your parameter to it (es. `var url = {$currentURL} + '?attr=attrValue'`)
4. Now you have just to call this URL.